# Obtener un dato de MySQL y colocarlo en un campo de un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas y quisiera aprender algo que aun no sé, tengo un campo tipo texto y a este input quiero que le aparezca como valor predeterminado, el nombre del usuario que tiene la sesión activa dentro del [![sistema. Es decir, por ejemplo: si yo inicie sesión en el sistema y yo soy un]  vendedor, en el formulario hay un campo que se llama vendedor y es ahi donde quiero que aparezca automático mi nombre en ese campo. la tabla de donde quiero extraer el dato se llama: **usuarios** y el campo de la tabla se llama **nombre_usuario**

este es el campo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No somos adivinos, hermano. ¿Puedes agregar el código que lleves hecho? También te recomiendo que pases por este link [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular mejor tus pregunta.

Comment: Quizá debas poner todo lo que llevas en código, a simple vista pudieras obtener el dato con Php al inicio de tu código mediante alguna función o método y luego mediante echo pasarlo al campo que quieres. Ahora también puedes usar Javascript para obtener el dato y de esta forma mostrarlo en el campo que desees

Answer (score 0):

Debes extraer los datos del usuario para la validación de tu base de datos

```
$usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['usuario']);
$pass= md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']));
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario='$usuario' AND password='$pass'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Y luego almacenar tus datos de $_session mediante los datos de la query

```
if($result>0)
          {
              $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
              $_SESSION['active'] = true;
              $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
              $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];
              $_SESSION['correo'] = $data['correo'];
              $_SESSION['usuario'] = $data['nombre_usuario'];                   
      }
      else{
        $alert = 'El usuario o la clave son incorrectos';
        session_destroy();
      }
```

Después podrás acceder a los datos de tu usuario mediante $_SESSION sin problemas

```
<input type= "text" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']?>" />
```